# How to get the Yup conditional validation to work with Formik in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, formik, yup

I have a Formik form that has two radio buttons that would ask the user to choose if he is a staff member or a student and based on his selection then I will be able to show different fields for the user to fill out using Yup validation.
I am not sure how to use the when() method here !!

Here is my Formik

```
<Formik
        initialValues ={{
            name: '',
            school: '',
            jobType: '',
            parentName: '',
            parentPhone: '',
            parentEmail: '',
            staffPhone:'',
            staffEmail: '',
            condition:'',
        }}
        onSubmit={async (values) => {
          await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }}
        validationSchema={validate}
   
    
    >

I am trying to use Yup validation to show the fields based on the users choice
my validation Schema

const validate = Yup.object({
    name: Yup.string()
             .max(20, "Must be 20 characters or less" )
             .required('required'),
    school: Yup.string().required('Please select your school').oneOf(schools),
    jobType: Yup.string().required("are you a student or a staff member ?!"),
    parentName: Yup.string().when('jobType', {
      is: true ,
      then: Yup.string().required('Field is required')
    }),
```

as for the form itself :

```
 <div id="my-radio-group">Job type</div>
     <ErrorMessage name="jobType" />

<div role="group" aria-labelledby="my-radio-group">
<label>
<Field type="radio" name="jobType" value="student" />
Student
</label>
<label>
<Field type="radio" name="jobType" value="staff member" />
Staff member</label>

{console.log({values})}
{/* <div>Picked: {values.jobType}</div>  */}
</div> 
    <button className="btn btn-dark mt-3" type="submit"> Register</button>
```

Comment: Just in case it might help, I did a small edit to yhe yup validation hoping it would work 

parentName: Yup.string().when('jobType', {
      is: (value) => value === "student",
      then: Yup.string().required('Field is required')
    }),

However still nothing is showing up !!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do some conditional rendering of the fields you want based on the value the jobType.
The jobType is expected to be a string that can take on one of the two values "staff member" or "student" depending on the radio selected.
In your case, jobType is being checked against a boolean value true which is wrong. This should be checked against either of the two strings "student" or "staff member".

You should change your validation schema to something like this:

```
   const validate = Yup.object({
    name: Yup.string()
      .max(20, "Must be 20 characters or less")
      .required("Required!"),
    school: Yup.string()
      .required("Please select your school")
      .oneOf(schools),
    jobType: Yup.string().required("Are you a student or a staff member?"),
    parentName: Yup.string().when('jobType', {
      is: "student",
      then: Yup.string().required("Field is required")
    }),
    parentEmail: Yup.string().when('jobType', {
      is: "student",
      then: Yup.string().required("Field is required")
    }),
    staffPhone: Yup.string().when('jobType', {
      is: "staff member",
      then: Yup.string().required("Field is required")
    }),
    staffEmail: Yup.string().when('jobType', {
      is: "staff member",
      then: Yup.string().required("Field is required")
    })
  })
```

When rendering your form it should be dependent on the values in the jobType like so:

```
         {
            values.jobType === "student" 
            && 
            <>
              <label>
                Parent Name
                <Field type="text" name="parentName" placeholder="Enter name" />
              </label>
              <ErrorMessage name="parentName"/>

              <label>
                Parent Email
                <Field type="text" name="parentEmail" placeholder="Enter name" />
              </label>
              <ErrorMessage name="parentEmail"/>
            </>
          }
          {
            values.jobType === "staff member" 
            && 
            <>
              <label>
                StaffPhone
                <Field type="text" name="staffName" placeholder="Enter name" />
              </label>
              <ErrorMessage name="staffName"/>

              <label>
                StaffEmail
                <Field type="text" name="staffEmail" placeholder="Enter name" />
              </label>
              <ErrorMessage name="staffEmail"/>
            </>
          }
```

You can also checkout the entire code in my
[sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-formik-question-1-u7dpfp).